# Save a .txt file in local storage

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can save a .txt file in the local storage and load it back in later? I have an file input element in html where I can load in files. The problem is, that when I reload the code I always need to reselect the file...

Comment: File as object - no. Content - yes. But localStorage has limited max size

Comment: yeah, just save it in local storage :)

Comment: [Take a loot at this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/)

Comment: _“when I reload the code I always need to reselect the file”_ — There is no way to work around this; I can imagine there would be security implications otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can save only content but not files. If you have the possibility to read out the text file on the server and pack it into a json, then you can read out the json on the client side and pack it into your local storage.

If you do not have a server available, you can do this on the client side with: new XMLHttpRequest();. Read the file and save the content in your localstorage. In this sense: `localStorage.setItem('MyContentFromTextFile', content)`